# Why the accusative comes before the dative in these examples (2 substantives)?

Tags: translation, accusative

I've been reading when there's two substantives, the dative case comes first, then the accusative's. But I came across these two examples:

> Ich suche ein Zimmer in einer WG
>
> Ich suche ein Flugticket nach Neuseeland

Why in these two cases, the accusative comes first?

Comment: The rule is only about dative and accusative *objects*. What you have here is *prepositional phrases* in the dative case.

Comment: "Dative before accusative" is in no way a strict rule, BTW. It's just more common. "Ich gebe den Ball dem Hund" and "Ich gebe dem Hund den Ball" are functionally close to equivalent and both correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry for my *layman* explanation, but there's no *dative* substantive in those examples you give.

Just the order of substantives appearing in a german sentence, doesn't automatically identify these as *accusative* or *dative* substantives.

To cite *wikipedia* (probably not the best resource here):

> > Als Test zum Nachweis eines Akkusativ-Objekts dient im Deutschen die Frage **Wen oder was**?

That would match the terms *`"Flugticket"`* and *`"Zimmer"`* in your examples.

But I can't spot a *dative* case, which would be defined as ([wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dativ) again)

> > Für den Dativ wird im Deutschen die Frage **Wem?** benutzt.

The substantives appearing in those parts *`"nach Neuseeland"`*, *`"in einer WG"`* aren't dative subjectives, but merely additional attributions to the *accusative* substantives, and thus naturally are placed **after** the related *accusative substantives*.

Comment: I was pretty confused here about that, I 'swear' they were datives. You were pretty clear, thanks!

Comment: @humble I mentioned that weird sounding _"Yoda Grammar"_ _"Nach Neuseeland ein Flugticket suche ich."_ in my 1st comment ;-).